# Building custom route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I have this route:

`put 'workstations' => 'workstation#update'`

that I'm intending to match up with this link:

`link_to "Update", controller: "workstations", action: "update", :method => :put`

but I'm getting this error and I don't know why:

`No route matches {:controller=>"workstations", :action=>"update", :method=>:put}`

How can I build the route and why isn't what I've specified working?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a spelling error.

You wrote:

```
put 'workstations' => 'workstation#update'
```

But the controller name should be plural as in:

```
put '/workstations' => 'workstations#update'
```

Also, you can always run `rake routes` and get the list of generated routes and route names in your app.

### EDIT

By the way, you can achieve the same routes generation with the following, more elegant way:

```
resource :workstations, only: :update
```

Comment: I've been around and around with this app, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972709/can-i-use-resource-routes-without-a-database-without-ids), but you're right, this case was a spelling error.